# how do you access all properties of a object to add them up

Tags: javascript, object

The orderSupplies function takes two arguments: a supplies object with keys of party supplies and values of the cost of that supply, and the number of guests attending.

It should return a number showing the total cost of ordering one of each item per guest!

```
orderSupplies({ cake: 2, iceCream: 7 }, 2);
// should return 18

orderSupplies({ plates: 2, cups: 1, forks: 1, partyHats: 4 }, 20);
// should return 160

function orderSupplies(supplies, guests) {
// Your code goes here...
    let total = 0 
     for (let i = 0; i < supplies.length; i++){
      total += supplies
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: I would start by figuring out how to access the properties on an object.

Comment: i'd acccess the properties by using dot operator, i.e supplies.plates

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values()` will get you all values of an object and `Array.prototype.reduce()` will help you sum them up:

```js
console.log(orderSupplies({ cake: 2, iceCream: 7 }, 2));
// 18
console.log(orderSupplies({ plates: 2, cups: 1, forks: 1, partyHats: 4 }, 20));
// 160

function orderSupplies(obj,count){
 return Object.values(obj).reduce((a,c)=>a+c)*count
}
```